# Why can I sometimes see the Yeti through walls in Mei's Yeti Hunt?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes when playing as the Hunter (Mei) in Mei's Yeti Hunt, I'll briefly see the Yeti (Winston) through walls as a red spot. This is the same effect from Widowmaker's Infra-Sight or Hanzo's Scatter Arrow.

Why can I sometimes see the Yeti through walls as the Hunter?

[image: Seeing the Yeti as a red outline]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anytime your teammate hits the Yeti you can see his location for a short time, even through walls.

This is shown on the Hero Ability menu as the passive ***Teamwork*** ability.

[image: Teamwork ability on Hero Info menu]